# Use values() in Django query to get Model instead of ID

Tags: python, django

I have the following setup in Django

```
class Class1(Model):

    search_field = IntegerField()
    field2 = ForeignKey(Class2)

class Class2(Model):

    field3 = ForeignKey(Class3)

class Class3(Model):

    #lots of useful stuff...
```

I am doing a query in `Class1` with the intention of getting back an instance of `Class3`, however `Class1` and `Class2` have a lot of information that I don't want to load, so I want to use `values` (or something that lets me do this more efficiently).  I do something like

```
q = Class1.objects.filter(search_field=search_criteria).values('field2__field3').latest()
```

But when this comes back I get a dictionary that looks like:

```
{'field2__field3': ID}
```

Where `ID` is a key to an instance of `Class3`.  Is there a way to get the instance of the class directly from `values` (or some other query utility)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple rule with Django queries is to always query on the thing you want to get back. So if you want a `Class3`, start your query with that.

```
Class3.objects.filter(class2__class1__search_field=search_criterion).latest()
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your solution, in this scenario `Class3` does not have a `ForeignKey` back to `Class2`...so how can I walk that back in a query?

Comment: Django follows foreign keys backwards automatically, so `Class2` having the FK to `Class3` means you can also reverse the lookup. See the test beginning with "It works backwards, too" here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships

Answer (score 4):

Rewrite your code to:

```
q = Class3.objects.filter(class2__class1__search_field=search_criteria)
```

I.e. directly ask for the objects you really want, and use the reverse relationships from Class3 back to Class2 and Class1 as part of your filter criteria.

It may help to set `related_name` or `related_query_name` on the `ForeignKey`s that you are using - if set, these are the names to use in the filter() arguments.  If not set, they default to the class name.